# How does this snippet validate an integer input?

Tags: c++, validation

I get the loop, and the initial prompt for input of type int, but... what is the while loop checking with  !(cin >> [variable])? I looked at cin on cplusplus.com for an explanation but I don't see it holding any value ... it looks like it's just checking the numerical value of the number entered, how would that check for a valid integer input?

```
int number;
.
.
.
    cout<<"Please enter a number: ";
    while (!(cin >> number))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin >> badinput;
        cout <<"Input " << badinput << " is invalid, please enter a number: ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator >>` on an input stream returns a reference to the stream, not the thing read from the stream.  The value read is placed into what the argument references, which must be an lvalue.

The `!` operator on an iostream tests the failure flag on on the stream -- it returns true if there's been any sort of failure on the stream.  For an input stream, if you attempt to read an integer (as this code is doing) and the input doesn't look like an integer, the fail flag will be set.

So this code (attempts to) read an integer into `number` and then tests the fail flag.  If it's set, it clears the fail flag, reads `badinput` (probably a string), prints the message and loops, attempting to read another integer.

So as long as the only failure is with the formatting, it will loop until it gets an integer.  If there's some other more persistent failure (eg, if cin gets an EOF or is closed), it will loop forever.

Comment: Thanks! This will help me a lot in making my code not explode in my homework, but I don't want to use something I don't understand :D

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like it will check if a positive number is entered.  A positive number will be true, causing `!number` to be false and skip the loop.  If it is not a positive number that is entered, it will be false, causing `!number` to be true and enter the loop.

Comment: A comment with the down-vote would be helpful to avoid future down-votes.

Comment: @NickD: Your explanation is wrong. Whether a number is positive or negative doesn't make it true or false. By convention, 0 is false, and anything other than zero is true. Therefore, !7 = !-3 = !true = false and !0 = !false = true. Try calling this function with many different values for `x`, including -1, 0 and 1: `void test(int x) { if(x) { printf("%d: true!\n", x); } if(!x) { printf("%d: false!\n", x); } }`

Comment: @NikBougalis Thank you for the explanation, that was helpful.  It seems some people here forget that this site is for learning and think everyone is an expert, resulting in very condescending and unhelpful comments.

Comment: @NickD: If you have a question, you should ask it as a question, not put it in as an answer to another (unrelated) question and expect people to clarify things in the comments.  Your answer, besides being wrong, has essentially nothing to do with the question asked.  This site it not specifically for learning, its for asking and answering questions that can't easily be asked and answered somewhere else.  Questions on the basic syntax of programming languages are borderline as they are often better addressed by reading an introductory text.