# Ask user to enter an integer an if its not an integer ask user to re-enter the value c++

Tags: c++

While input is a letter this works fine but if I input a float number, for example 5.5 it stops. The question is how can I check if a float or double is entered?

```cpp
int main(){
 
  int a;

  cout << "enter a number:" << endl;

  while(!(cin>>a)) {
       cin.clear();
   
       cin.ignore(256,'\n');
   
       cout << "wrong input\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this snippet validate an integer input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595461/how-does-this-snippet-validate-an-integer-input)

Comment: Read *lines*, and then try to convert the lines into numbers (including validation) with e.g. [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: What does your code do if `42foobar` is entered? Is this what you want? What about `42 foobar`?

Comment: @Botje his issue is different it is corner case of distinguish input of integer and floating point.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
int main()
{
    double in;
    double ceil_in;
    double diff;

    do {
        while (!(std::cin >> in))
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(123, '\n');
        }
        ceil_in = ceil(in);
        diff = in - ceil_in;
    } while(diff != 0.0);
    std::cout << "Finish." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now it should work with strings too. Let me know if it addresses your problem.

Comment: And then what happens if a `string` is passed by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Just read whole line then try read integer from it checking if everything was read.

```cpp
bool scan_int(const std::string& s, int& x) {
    std::istringstream in{s};
    return in >> x >> std::ws && in.eof();
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;

    while(std::getline(std::cin, s)) {
        int x;
        if (scan_int(s, x)) {
            std::cout << "Integer found: " << x << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cout << '"' << s << "\" is not an integer\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/xdcjzrEEd

Answer (score 0):

Two questions in one!

1. How do I repeat some code multiple times?
2. How do I read an integer from standard input?

This answer attempts to separate those 2 questions and also to show an extendable approach, just in case your next homework assignment will be to read not an int but a float or a hex number or 5 integers or whatever... and maybe from a file and not standard input...

For question 1, see `main()` in the code below, for question 2, see `read_fixnum()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

bool read_fixnum(std::istream& is,
         std::string prompt,
         int& result) {
  std::regex fixnum{"\\s*(\\d+)\\s*"};
  std::cout << prompt << std::endl;
  std::string line;
  if (std::getline(is,line)) {
    std::smatch match_result;
    if (std::regex_match(line, match_result, fixnum)) {
      result = std::stoi(match_result.str());
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

  int number = 0;
  bool running = true;
  while (running) {
    if (read_fixnum(std::cin,
            "enter an integral number: ",
            number)) {
      running = false;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "you entered: " << number << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A regex is really overkill for this. Especially since you use `std::stoi` which have built-in validation (so you validate the input twice).

Comment: Indeed - I should just use `atoi()` here!